# Can Lord Vishnu be a Kuldevta?

Tags: gotra

Today my grandfather told me that our Kuldevta is Lord Vishnu and I had a hard time believing it. Is it possible to have Vishnu as a Kuldevta? If yes then which Rishi was originated from Lord Vishnu?

Comment: why not? most vaishnavas have vishnu (in archa-murti form at some temple or holy site) as kula devata.

Comment: @ram I've read this in another answer that if you trace back your ancestors, you'll find that they were oroginated from a Rishi who himself was originated through your Kuldevta. Does that mean they are originated from Lord Vishnu himself? It's hard to believe because he's one of the biggest Gods hindus pray to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible.

A famous example: The *kuladevata* of the Travancore royal family was *Padmanābha*, Lord Vishnu. The kings from this house even carried the title "Padmanābhadāsa", servant of Vishnu. They considered Lord Vishnu to be the true ruler of the country and themselves to be mere custodians.

The *kuladevata* of most Iyengar brahmins (who belong to the *Sri Vaishnava* tradition) is Vishnu.